# How to play song unlimited time?

Tags: music

There are 2 songs in my playlist. I want to listen first song once then secondary song unlimited times. How to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which music player do you use? Have you tried the repeat mode on?

Comment: There should be an option "[Repeat all](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=repeat+all+icon)". That would do the job.

Comment: @Firelord Repeat all would repeat both infinitely, not just the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Just listen to the first song as normal.
When the second one starts playing click on the [**repeat(1)**](https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_repeat_one_48px-128.png) button and...

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

[VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) allows you to easily loop files/playlists.